# Spring Boot поиск по базе (findAllByAuthor)

Tags: база-данных, spring, spring-boot

Необходимо в Spring Boot приложении сделать поиск по базе и вывести на странице список проектов которые созданы пользователем под которым произведена авторизация. Использую Spring Boot, PostgresSQL, Freemarker.
При использовании метода findByAll() все отлично находит и выводит на странице список записей из таблицы, при использовании метода findAllByAuthor() страница пустая.

Код:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String prj_name;

private String uniqid;

private boolean is_public;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User author;

public Project() {
}

public Project(String prj_name, String uniqid, boolean is_publiuc, User author) {
    this.prj_name = prj_name;
    this.uniqid = uniqid;
    this.author = author;
    this.is_public = is_publiuc;
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
public interface ProjectsRepo extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {
Project findByUniqid(String code);
Project findAllByAuthor(User user);
```

}

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "projects")
public class ProjectController {

@Autowired
ProjectsRepo projectsRepo;

@GetMapping
public String projectList(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("projects", projectsRepo.findAllByAuthor(user));
    return "projects";
}
```

Шаблон странницы:

```
<#list projects as project>
  <div>
   <span>${project.id}</span>
   <a href="/notes/${project.id}">${project.prj_name}</a>
   <a href="/projects/${project.id}">Settings</a>
  </div>
</#list>
```

При заходе на странницу ничего не отображает, просто пустая странница, в логе ИДЕИ пишет следующий Exception:

```
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 5
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1471) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
```

Судя по логу он нашёл 5 записей, но почему он не выводит их на странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в объявлении метода репозитория, вы указали единственный экземпляр в виде возращаемого значения, а нужно было коллекцию

```
List<Project> findAllByAuthor(User user);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)